# How to get long-link from dynamic link when opening app for the first time?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, url, firebase-dynamic-links

When I click on a dynamic link I will be redirected to the appstore and from there I download the app. What I really need is the long link of the dynamic link because I got data in it which I need to extract.

This method will be opened when I start the app for the first time:

```
-(Bool)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDICtionarry<NSString *, id>options).
```

Comment: Another thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451072/how-to-know-app-was-installed-through-firebase-dynamic-link-in-didfinishlaunchin/47504123?noredirect=1#comment82399834_47504123

Answer (score 1):

Clarification of terms here:
deep link -> this is what you will put inside dynamic link;
long dynamic link -> dynamic link that has your deep link and bunch of parameters related to dynamic link behavior;
short dynamic link - the same as long but has short representation;

To store more data you need to add your data as parameters to deep link. For example instead of deep link `https://example.com` you use `https://example.com?promotionID=abc&openViewName=startingViewOptionB&loadImageOnPromo=imageSmall`

Let me know if have questions.

Comment: But I really don't want to make all those dynamic links in firebase. I only want to make 1 and add data to it depends on how many people I will send the link to. So when someone clicks on this "https://****.app.goo.gl/jGBo" I want to extract data from it and use it. Hope you can help me out with this one.

Comment: I tahink I got it sir! Let me get it working and will let you know asap!

Comment: Ivanow Is there a way to add data to a dynamic link programatically? So for example the dynamic link I have created on firebase looks like this "https://****.app.goo.gl/jGBo" and the deeplink looks like this "https://example.com/home". How can I programatically change the deeplink url? If someone opens the dynamic link on a device it should be redirected too the mobile device so I cant send the deeplink, I have to send the dynamic link which contains the deeplink I have added in firebase. But I can't change that deeplink. Please help me out with this one.

Comment: @Ivanov I also foudn this on firebase website 

"Using the Dynamic Link Builder API on iOS and Android. This is the preferred way to dynamically create links in your app for user-to-user sharing or in any situation that requires many links. You can track the performance of Dynamic Links created with the Builder API using the Dynamic Links Analytics API."

Is this a solution? I really prefer to make a dynamic link on firebase, add data to the long link and receive the longlink in the openURL method. Which isn't working, I only receive the deeplink url.

Comment: @Ivanov That is why I need to receive data from the longlink in my app. I only receive the deeplink in my app if the app is started for the firsttime through the "openURL" method. the "continueuseractivity" method will give me a long link but that method isn't called when someone clicks on the link and after they are being redirected to the appstore and downlaod the app. The method just isn't called. So I need to have access to the long link through the "openURL" method or edit the deeplink programatically which isn't possible I guess...

Comment: @Ivanov Everytime I want to send an invitation link to someone I need to place data in the deeplink. So how can I do that? Do I need to make a dynamic link programmatically? Hope to hear from you sir!

Comment: Use this https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create to create links on iOS. If you still have issues receiving links, post you code of UIApplicationDelegate's openURL: and continueuseractivity: methods.

Comment: @Ivanow Thank for helping me out. I've fixed this issue by creating the dynamiclink programmatically with the example of the link you had send me. Thanks again!